# Active Record, Fill The Textfield With Autocomplete in yii?

Tags: activerecord, yii, autocomplete

I want, i choose food's name with autocomplete and selected food's name shown in autocomplete and selected food's calory shown in other textfield and selected food's id record in my table with activerecord...

I success select food with autocomplete and fill the other textfield food's calory but i dont record this food id in my table.

I have a table, Yemekler
This table's fields ; id yemekAdi niteligi kalori

When i click the submit button, i want to selected food's id record the in my database. But form send food's name for record. Due to the value not integer, record not success.

Thanks for help.

My codes at below

menu.php view

```
<div class="row">
    <?php 
        echo $form->labelEx($model,'yemek1'); 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
            'model'=>$model->yemek1,
            'name'=>'Menu_yemek1',
            'source'=>$this->createUrl('kayit/autocompleteTest'),
            'options'=>array(
                'delay'=>300,
                'minLength'=>1,
                'showAnim'=>'fold',
                'focus'=>'js:function(event, ui) {
                    $("#Menu_yemek1").val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                }',
                'select'=>"js:function(event, ui) {
                    $('#Menu_yemek1').val(ui.item.label);
                    $('#kalori1').val(ui.item.kalori1);
                    return false;
                }",
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'size'=>'40'
            ),
        ));

        echo $form->error($model,'yemek1');
    ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::textField('kalori1', '', array('id'=>'kalori1', 'disabled' => true)); ?>
</div>
```

KayitController.php controller

```
public function actionAutocompleteTest() {
    $res =array();

    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $sql = 'SELECT yemekAdi as label, id as value, kalori as kalori1 FROM yemekler ';
        $sql = $sql . ' WHERE  niteligi=1 and yemekAdi LIKE :label'; // Must be at least 1
        $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $command->bindValue(":label", '%'.$_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        echo json_encode ($command->queryAll());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possibilities:

1. In the controller after clicking the submit button you get the food id using a SQL request and the name of the food that has been submitted
2. In the autocomplete you also return the id of the food and store it in an `hidden field` (using javascript). This way you won't have to perform another request in the `Controller`!

Please tell me what option you want to use, I'll post some code accordingly to it!